# Function name indentifier from another source file is undefined

Tags: c++

Compiler issues an error that the identifier "func" is undefined:

[image]

I don't know why this error occurs because I link the header file, with the declaration of this function. I use Visual Studio 2017 Community.

My code:

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once

class Foo {
    friend void func();
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

void func()
{
}
```

**bar.h**

```
#pragma once

class Bar {
    void baz();
};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"

void Bar::baz()
{
    func(); // indentifier "func" is undefined
}
```

Comment: Edit your question, show the error, correct your spelling. And wrong, header is not for linking.

Comment: Add the declaration `void func(void);` to "foo.h".

Comment: Mind showing where you defined func?  because it isn't in your question hence your error.

Comment: Your `foo` class needs the declaration of `func` before the class.  Use a forward declaration.

Comment: This `friend void func();` is **not a declaration**.

Comment: Alright I will try to explain this simply, bar and foo are not related in any way, you have not listed any of them as being a friend class, so your error is because bar is trying to access a func definition from the bar class (Which is not declared or defined). not foo(like you believe it is), and bar also has no instances of foo to call that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the function.

```
void func();
```

Declaring a function as `friend` to a class **does not declare the function** to anything else - the function will only be visible to class Foo. So you should actually declare that function.

To be less confusing: Declaring the **existence** of a function is different from declaring its **`friend`ship** to a class.

Comment: They why, if in `foo.h` `func` is not declared, how is a `friend`ship declaration allowed?

Comment: @Al.G. It makes it visible to class Foo, but not necessarily to anything else.